# Making a Win/Loss file for CRAPS, If statement isn't working

Tags: vhdl

I am here wondering what I am doing wrong in my code that my if statement isn't working. I'm making a win/loss file for the game CRAPS in Vivado and can't figure out why I'm getting an error. I'd love any sort of insight on my problem as I am quite not as experience coding in VHDL. 
Ports: num : in STD_LOGIC_vector(5 downto 0) & WL : inout std_logic_vector (4 downto 0)

architecture Behavioral of winloss is
begin
with num select

```
    **WL <= "1" when "0010",**     Error starts here, say's syntax error near if
          "1" when "0011",
          "0" when "0100",
          "0" when "0101",
          "0" when "0110",
          "0" when "0111",
          "0" when "1000",
          "0" when "1001",
          "0" when "1010",
          "0" when "1011",
          "1" when "1100",
          "1" when others;

          if WL = '0' then
            report "WIN"
                countW +1;

          elsif WL = '1' then
            report "LOSS"
            countL + 1;
           end if;
```

Comment: That was my accident, I meant to delete that, disregard it.

Comment: See [help], [ask]

Comment: `WL <= "1" when "0010",` What are you evaluating "0010" against? Are you intending to use a selected signal assignment statement or a conditional signal assignment statement (the syntax is incorrect for either). Further you assign WL a bit string literal of length one while evaluating WL against character literal values in the if statement conditions. Likewise the expression incrementing countL or countW are not part of the syntax of a report statement.  Provide a [mcve]. You have numerous syntax errors and a semantic error or two to choose from.

Comment: Please format your code properly, use the formatting for code and provide a complete example. This can't compile and as such we can't help